# How to pick top N values with tie using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(gene_ratio = c(0.636363636363636, 0.571428571428571, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.454545454545455, 0.454545454545455, 0.444444444444444, 
0.428571428571429, 0.357142857142857)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 1
   gene_ratio
        <dbl>
 1      0.636
 2      0.571
 3      0.5  
 4      0.5  
 5      0.5  
 6      0.455
 7      0.455
 8      0.444
 9      0.429
10      0.357
```

What I want to do is to pick top 5 values with ties yielding:

```
   gene_ratio
     0.636
     0.571
     0.5  
     0.5  
     0.5  
     0.455
     0.455
     0.444
```

How can I achieve that?
I tried:

```
  df %>%
  dplyr::top_n(n = 5, wt = gene_ratio)
```

But failed.

Answer (score 2):

```
n <- 5
  
df %>%
  mutate(Snum = cumsum(!duplicated(gene_ratio))) %>%
  filter(Snum <= n) %>%
  select(gene_ratio)
```

Output

```
   gene_ratio
       <dbl>
1      0.636
2      0.571
3      0.5  
4      0.5  
5      0.5  
6      0.455
7      0.455
8      0.444
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>% filter(dense_rank(-gene_ratio) %in% 1:5)
```

OR

```
df %>% filter(as.integer(ordered(-gene_ratio)) %in% 1:5)
```

OR

```
df %>% filter(data.table::frank(-gene_ratio, ties.method = "dense") %in% 1:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    arrange(desc(gene_ratio)) %>% 
    filter(gene_ratio %in% head(unique(gene_ratio), 5))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 1
  gene_ratio
       <dbl>
1      0.636
2      0.571
3      0.5  
4      0.5  
5      0.5  
6      0.455
7      0.455
8      0.444
```

---

`top_n` is getting replaced with `slice` functions.  An option with `slice_max` can be

```
df %>% 
    slice_max(order_by = gene_ratio, 
        n = sum(tail(sort(table(df$gene_ratio)), 5)))
# A tibble: 8 x 1
  gene_ratio
       <dbl>
1      0.636
2      0.571
3      0.5  
4      0.5  
5      0.5  
6      0.455
7      0.455
8      0.444
```